# Image is displayed unusually big when inside a page

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I have this image:

http://www.problemio.com/img/phoneimage.png

But when I placed in inside a page like this:

```
<div style="float:left">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Z5U.png" style="border: none;"  />
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<p>
Some text
</p>
<p>
Some text
</p>
</div>
```

It got displayed as very big.  Here is how it looks on a test page:
http://problemio.com/business/business_economics.php

Would anyone know why that happened? It is really unexpected. Here is the css I am working with

```
/* layout styles across the problemio project */ 

html 
{ 
    background-color: #ECE5B6;
    #4a4647; 
}

body, html 
{
    padding: 5px;

}

body 
{
    font-family:  "Century Gothic",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    #background-color: #5C5957;
    #background-color: #4a4647;



    #background:url(/img/ui/background_image.png) top left no-repeat;
    #background-size: 100%; 
}

 /* makes the background of the top bar gray */
.container 
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;

    overflow:hidden;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.container_home 
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;

    overflow:hidden;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#bd 
{
       /* background-color: #f5f6f6; */ /* some form of gray */
        background-color: white;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
}


/* styles for banner: */ 
.banner 
{
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    background-size:100%;
    #background-color: #4a4647;


}

.site_title 
{
    float:left; 
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: 10px;

    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffce2e;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-size:2.5em;
    text-align: left
    text-color: black;
    width: 300px;
}

.site_login 
{
    width: 700px;
    float:right; 
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px; 
    font-size: 90.0%;
    color: gray;

    text-align: right;
    text-align: bottom;

}
/*
.bgdiv
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    left:240px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-image: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/banner_background.png');
    #background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
*/



/* styles for basic template */
.content .basic
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #888;

    border-color: gray; 
    text-align: left;
}

.content .basic h1{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center; 
}

.content .basic h2{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.content .basic h3{
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#layout 
{ 
    /*margin:auto; */
    #margin-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;

    text-align:left; 

   /*     background-color: #EDEDED; */

}

label span 
{
  float: left;
  width: 15em;
}

p.half_text
{
    font-size: 80.0%;
    font-type: arial;

}

span.half_text
{
    font-size: 80.0%;
    font-type: arial;

}

p.half_height
{
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.index_problem_title:visited
{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.index_problem_title
{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.index_problem_title:hover 
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: gray;
}

footer a
{
    color: white;
}

div.footer 
{
text-align: right;
#color:#999999;
color: white;
background-color: black;
font-family:arial,times,serif;
font-size:18px;
#padding-top:20px;
line-height:150%;
position:relative;
float:right;
bottom:10px;
#height: 100px;
style: clear:both;
width: 1000px;
#background:url(/img/ui/footerbar.png) top left no-repeat;
}

#tabs-1
{
    padding-left: 10px; !important;
}

.ui-tabs-panel
{
   padding: 5px !important;
}

.ui-widget-header
{
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.ui-state-default
{
    background-image: none;
    background-color: Gray;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the same size to me .. is this specific to a browser?

Comment: set the image width to be 100% in the CSS

Comment: @ExplosionPills my browser is Chrome

Comment: @Genadinik click on the image when you're on http://www.problemio.com/img/phoneimage.png you'll see its real size.

Comment: Same size, Chrome, FF and IE... it's just that browsers scale large images to fit in screen

Comment: @JEES that makes sense. So should I just set the display to 70% ? Or what would be the fix to get it to show up as in the link here: http://www.problemio.com/img/phoneimage.png

Comment: `<img src="http://www.problemio.com/img/phoneimage.png" width="60%" height="60%" style="border: none;">`

Comment: I guess it's much better if you do that with Photoshop since the image size will decrease from 892KB to 383KB

Comment: Here is the images scaled to 60% http://mi-creativity.com/test/images/phoneimage2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make adjacent,

```
<div style="float: left; width: 68%; display: inline;">
    <img width="60%" height="60%" style="border: none;" src="http://www.problemio.com/img/phoneimage.png">
</div>

<div style="display: inline; float: left; width: 28%;">
<p>
Understanding and correctly forecasting the unit economics of your business is extremely important. It is a large part of a successful business plan, and the business itself.  The term might sound complicated, but it is surprisingly simple. At least we will try to make it so with an example.
</p>
<p>
In an effort to make this material easy and fun to understand, we will actually go over the unit economics of a real business. Our example business: A single-location exercise gym. We will call it Bob's Fitness.
</p>
</div>
```

Actually , I just added some inline css to your code,you can made them in class or id also

Comment: thank you, that almost worked. Would you know why the image and the text are so far apart on the page now?  I put your code live so you can actually see how it worked

Comment: just little info:
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="float:left;width:49%></div>
    <div style="float:right;width:49%></div>
</div>

above div will be adjacent to each other.you can modify width, but beware IE and other browser who treat border and other property differently.Always leave space for div so that they would not go in next line

Comment: because you sized the image to be 60% of the parent div which was 68% of its parent too! so there is the "blank" part. try to size the image 98%. Tested and working. <img width="98%" style="border: none;" (do not put the height)

Comment: to make image and text next to each other, play with width.Once  satisfied save.

Answer (score 1):

```
#layout div img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Add this css in your page or place as you want.

Comment: thank you. That made it fit into the page. But what I actally needed was to align text next to it so I just wanted to have the image appear as its normal width

Answer (score 1):

I see you are modifying it :-) i'm testing with firebug!

In any case I tested it there

http://jsfiddle.net/eb56N/2/

I've just added

```
<img style="border: none; width: 100%;" src="http://www.problemio.com/img/phoneimage.png">
```

Maybe you already changed something.